# DateTime object throwing error when passing date

Tags: php, datetime

I am using the following code and it works fine.

```
$boosterDate1 = $_POST['boosterDate1'];
//$boosterDate1 = changeDateFormat($boosterDate1);

date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
$myDateTime = new DateTime;
$myDateTime = $myDateTime->createFromFormat('m/d/y', $boosterDate1);
$boosterDate1 = $myDateTime->format('Y-m-d');
```

The problem I am having is when I create a function and try to call it multiple times on multiple dates.  For some reason when I pass the date to the following function I get the following error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

```
<?php 
function changeDateFormat($dateString){
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
    $myDateTime = new DateTime;
    $myDateTime = $myDateTime->createFromFormat('m/d/y', $dateString);
    $newDateString = $myDateTime->format('Y-m-d');
    return $newDateString;
}
?>
```

Any help is much appreciated.  I've looked through the manual and through many posts though can't figure out why it won't work when I pass the date to a function to do the same formatting on the date.

Comment: Please, note an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) is a `static` constructor.

Use this instead:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/y', $dateString);
```

Also, check for `$_POST['boosterDate1']` contents. If it is invalid, then `createFromFormat()` returns `false` (not object), according to the manual:

> Returns a new DateTime instance or FALSE on failure.

---

Improved function with test:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

$check = '12/20/14';

function changeDateFormat($dateString){
    $myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/y', $dateString);
    return $myDateTime->format('Y-m-d');
}

echo changeDateFormat($check);
?>
```

Shows:

```
2014-12-20
```

If you are using long year representation, change `'m/d/y'` to `'m/d/Y'`. It might cause an error.

Comment: This did work.  I'm confused as to why the original code didn't work though.  I create a new DateTime object then use creatFromFormat.  I'll have to look into static constructors to better understand it.  Thank you for your response as it did solve the problem.  I did try this way before but I must have had the wrong format and received the same error I was just getting.

Comment: @ndjustin20 also, note that you need to use `date_default_timezone_set()` just once for all date operations. Glad to help. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you again.  Unfortunately still too new to vote.  But I really do appreciate your help tonight.

Comment: @ndjustin20 toggle a `check mark` under the vote counter to select best answer. It will give reputation to asker and to answerer. Choose one answer, which helped mostly to solve your problem.